# Select inner join with n_m table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have three tables as following:

USERS TABLE

```
id_user| name |
---------------
1      | ...
2      | ...
```

SERVICES TABLE

```
id_service | name |
-------------------
1          | ...
2          | ...
3          | ...
```

USER_SERVICES TABLE (n-m)

```
id_user | id_service
--------------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 1
```

And I need to do a SELECT starting from "SELECT * FROM users" and then, getting the users by services. Ex. I need to get every user with services = 1 and services = 2 (and maybe he has other more services, but 1 and 2 for sure).

I did the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `users` 
INNER JOIN user_services ON users.id_user = user_services.id_user
WHERE id_service=1 AND id_service=2
```

But this, of course dont works since there is not a single record matching service = 1 and service = 2.

What can I do?

Comment: you mean users must be attached to serive 1 and 2 together ? Or either 1 or 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra join for the other service you want to check:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `users` 
INNER JOIN user_services us1 ON users.id_user = us1.id_user AND us1.id_service=1
INNER JOIN user_services us2 ON users.id_user = us2.id_user AND us2.id_service=2
```

Comment: Oh very funny. Can you provide the proper answer now please

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from user_services where id_user = t.id_user) how_much
  from users t;
```

Is this what you want???

It shows the data of the users and how much services are in the services table. Other possibility is this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when (select count(*) 
                       from user_services where id_user = 1) > 0 
        then 'service1' 
        else 'null'
        end) has_service_1
  from users t;
```

The problem with this select is that you have to repeat this case...end as much times as id_services you have, so it doesn't make sense if the number of services is increasing over time. On the contrary, if it is a somewhat fixed number, and it is not a big number, this could be a solution.

Comment: No... I need to put "service = 1 and service = 2" elsewhere to obtain users attaching with services.